# Django logging with multiple handlers for commands and views, with shared functions

Tags: python, django, logging

Is it possible to log commands and views to separate log files, while using a common function called from a command and a view ? Passing the logger as a function parameter would surely not be a good design.

**settings.py**

```
'loggers': {
    'Web': {
        'handlers': ['logfile_website'], # -> views.log
    'Commands': {
        'handlers': ['logfile_commands'], # -> commands.log
}
```

**views.py** -> goes to *views.log*

```
log = logging.getLogger('Web')
def index(request):
    log.info('In view')
    my_common.common_function(1)
```

**command.py** -> goes to *commands.log*

```
log = logging.getLogger('Commands')
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        log.info('In command')
        my_common.common_function(2)
```

**my_common.py**  -> goes to where needed based on caller

```
def common_function(param):
    log = How to get logger based on current call stack?
    log.info('In common function')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a single handler which uses a filename based on the environment. For example, on POSIX,

```
LOG_FILENAME = os.environ.get('LOGFILE', 'views.log')

# then use the filename in your configuration
```

and then run commands using

```
LOGFILE=commands.log python manage.py syncdb
```

where I am using `syncdb` as just an example of a command.